# Multiple drop down lists using Kivy library

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

I want to have multiple dropdown lists as a part of my application but some of them do not work and I don't know why.
The code for that is:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

class MidTopBar():
    def __init__(self):

        self.dropDownLabels = {
            "File"  : ['Example1', 'Example2','Example3', 'Example4'],
            "Edit"  : ['Example5', 'Example6','Example7', 'Example8'],
            "View"  : ['Example9', 'Example10','Example11', 'Example12'],
            "Help"  : ['Example13', 'Example14','Example15', 'Example16'],
        }
        self.generate()

         
    def _generateDropdown(self, name, list):
        dropdown = DropDown(auto_width = True,
                            width = 300)

        for index in range(len(list)):
            btn = Button(text=list[index],
                         halign = 'left',
                         valign = 'center',
                         padding_x= 20,
                         size_hint_y=None,
                         background_color = (1, 1, 1, 1))

            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(list[index]))
            btn.bind(size= btn.setter('text_size'))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        mainbutton = Button(text = name)

        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
        mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

        return mainbutton
    
    def _dropDowns(self):
        dropDownList = []
        for key in self.dropDownLabels:
            dropDownList.append(self._generateDropdown(name= key, list = self.dropDownLabels[key]))
        return dropDownList
                
    def generate(self):
        dropDownList = self._dropDowns()
        self.Box = BoxLayout()
        for dropDown in dropDownList:
            self.Box.add_widget(dropDown)
        self.emptyBox = BoxLayout()
        self.superBox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.superBox.add_widget(self.Box)
        self.superBox.add_widget(self.emptyBox)
        
class Example(App):
    
    def build(self):
        midTopBar       :object = MidTopBar().superBox
        return midTopBar

# Run the App of TextInput Widget in kivy
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```

I'm expecting all 4 lists in the constructor to be shown in their respective key buttons but only one or occasionally 2 works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are suffering from trash collection. Python automatically frees objects that have no saved reference in the code. Examples are your `MidTopBar` instance in your `build()` method, and the `dropdown` in your `_generateDropdown()` method. I have modified your code to save references to those objects, and it seems to fix it. First, I modified your `build()` method:

```
def build(self):
    # midTopBar: object = MidTopBar().superBox
    # return midTopBar
    self.mtb = MidTopBar()  # prevent trash collection of MidTopBar instance
    return self.mtb.superBox
```

And added a list to hold references to the `DropDown` instances. I the '**init**()` method:

```
class MidTopBar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dds = []
```

Then in the `_generateDropdown()` method, actually save the references:

```
def _generateDropdown(self, name, list1):
    dropdown = DropDown(auto_width=True,
                        width=300)
    self.dds.append(dropdown)  # just to protect from trash collection
```

There is another issue with the code line:

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(list[index]))
```

Because of the nature of `lambda`, this will always result in the last element of the `list` being selected. To correct this, use a temporary variable:

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn, t=text: dropdown.select(t))
```

This will result in the correct item being selected and shown in the `mainbutton`.

This is how `Dropdowns` are typically used, with the `mainbutton` showing the current selection. If you don't want the selection shown, you can replace the line:

```
btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn, t=text: dropdown.select(t))
```

with:

```
btn.bind(on_release=dropdown.dismiss)
```

Comment: Nicely done! You made my day...
I try to integrate it into my app and see if it works.
Thanks

Comment: Just notices that there is a bug using that solution, The name of the mainbutton  changes, when you select one of the items from the drop-down list.

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `Dropdown`. See updated answer.

Comment: Right, for my case I wanted to open a new window, rather than change the text Like a spinner.
So I defined a new event in the lambda function like you pointed out and now it works.
Thanks again